# Logo Keeps Changing to the Default for Transparent Settings

Tags: css, homepage, logo

I have a gallery displayed on my homepage with the transparent header setting option chosen. My transparent header is setup to have a white logo; however, Wordpress keeps utilizing the default logo which is black. The transparent setting works fine with all of the other pages, but I cannot get it to utilize the transparent logo for my homepage. Any assistance with code to override this would be appreciated.

The setting I have right now on the backend are as follows:

Image size: 200 x 90
Logo Top Space: 3px
Logo Bottom Space: 3px

Answer (score 0):

Many themes have page settings that allow you to change the logo for individual pages. Check that you are not overriding the global setting for the logo in your homepage settings.

Comment: I went through every menu and it looks like all of the page setting are maintained within the create a page window for each page. The customization page didn't have an option for it and the theme options didn't have anything for that setting as well. I am assuming there is some code in the theme that is requiring it to utilize the default logo. When I click on he transparent option for other pages it works.

Comment: What theme are you utilizing?

Comment: Glazov - Photography WordPress Theme by VictorThemes... I can't get any support because I purchased it with Envato Elements.